# Identical Java SerializedLambda returns different result for implMethodKind

Tags: java, serialization, lambda, runtime, bytecode

I'm Ronald, the author of [JobRunr](https://github.com/jobrunr/jobrunr). JobRunr is a background job scheduling library that uses SerializedLambda and ASM to analyze a Java 8 lambda and converts it to a background job.

Recently, an error was reported and I tried reproducing it in JobRunr so that I can write a test to prevent regression.

The funny thing is that on the same Java version (17.0.2), I cannot reproduce it even if I copy the exact code.

In [this project](https://github.com/rdehuyss/jobrunr-issue-serialized-lambda), the [generated](https://github.com/rdehuyss/jobrunr-issue-serialized-lambda/blob/main/src/main/java/org/example/GeoService.java) `SerializedLambda` has an `implMethodKind` equal to 5 (`REF_invokeVirtual`).

Yet, in JobRunr itself, the [generated](https://github.com/jobrunr/jobrunr/blob/1c181f95e160821d809681d7f93ad6b6f1963f64/tests/e2e-vm-jdk/src/main/java/org/jobrunr/tests/e2e/services/GeoService.java) `SerializedLambda` has an `implMethodKind` equal to 7 (`REF_invokeSpecial`).

The actual code to generate the `SerializedLambda` is as follows:

```java
public class GeoService {
    Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GeoService.class);

    public void executeGeoTreeJob(JobContext jobContext, long geoNameId, UserId userId) {
        LOG.error("Running: " + geoNameId);
    }

    public void run() {
        LOG.error("Starting job");
        UserId userId = new UserId();
        userId.setValue("test");
        long geoNameId = 1234;

        JobLambda jobLambda = () -> executeGeoTreeJob(JobContext.Null, geoNameId, userId);

        SerializedLambda serializedLambda = SerializedLambdaConverter.toSerializedLambda(jobLambda);
        System.out.println("=======");
        System.out.println("serializedLambda " + serializedLambda.getImplMethodKind());
        System.out.println("=======");

        BackgroundJob.enqueue(() -> executeGeoTreeJob(JobContext.Null, geoNameId, userId));
    }
}
```

In [this project](https://github.com/rdehuyss/jobrunr-issue-serialized-lambda), the [generated](https://github.com/rdehuyss/jobrunr-issue-serialized-lambda/blob/main/src/main/java/org/example/GeoService.java) `SerializedLambda` has an `implMethodKind` equal to 5 (`REF_invokeVirtual`).

Yet, in JobRunr itself, the [generated](https://github.com/jobrunr/jobrunr/blob/1c181f95e160821d809681d7f93ad6b6f1963f64/tests/e2e-vm-jdk/src/main/java/org/jobrunr/tests/e2e/services/GeoService.java) `SerializedLambda` has an `implMethodKind` equal to 7 (`REF_invokeSpecial`).

Why do I get different values for `implMethodKind`? Or, put differently, what do I need to do to the setup / JVM / ... to have the same results as in the example project.

**Update:**

I create the `SerializedLambda` as follows:

```java
public class SerializedLambdaConverter {

    private SerializedLambdaConverter() {

    }

    public static <T> SerializedLambda toSerializedLambda(T value) {
        if (!value.getClass().isSynthetic()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please provide a lambda expression (e.g. BackgroundJob.enqueue(() -> myService.doWork()) instead of an actual implementation.");
        }

        if (!(value instanceof Serializable)) {
            throw new JobRunrException("The lambda you provided is not Serializable. Please make sure your functional interface is Serializable or use the JobLambda interface instead.");
        }

        try {
            Method writeReplaceMethod = value.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("writeReplace");
            makeAccessible(writeReplaceMethod);
            return (SerializedLambda) writeReplaceMethod.invoke(value);
        } catch (Exception shouldNotHappen) {
            throw shouldNotHappenException(shouldNotHappen);
        }
    }
}
```

Below the output of `javap`:

```
Compiled from "GeoService.java"
public class org.jobrunr.tests.e2e.services.GeoService {
  org.slf4j.Logger LOG;
  public org.jobrunr.tests.e2e.services.GeoService();
  public void executeGeoTreeJob(org.jobrunr.jobs.context.JobContext, long, org.jobrunr.tests.e2e.services.UserId);
  public void run();
}
```

Attached the headers found in the output of `javap -verbose` (the full output is a bit too much for here in SO):

```
Classfile /Users/rdehuyss/Projects/Personal/jobrunr/jobrunr/tests/e2e-vm-jdk/build/classes/java/main/org/jobrunr/tests/e2e/services/GeoService.class
  Last modified 20 Feb 2024; size 4064 bytes
  SHA-256 checksum 595969292bcac503d33a4e54c1b2a4ffa7517f8aa6c50a8a1470400981e08ecb
  Compiled from "GeoService.java"
public class org.jobrunr.tests.e2e.services.GeoService
  minor version: 0
  major version: 52
```

Comment: I don’t get it. You are the author of JobRunr and have a question about what JobRunr does?

Comment: Hi @Holger - no, that would be easy. I struggle with the fact that the `SerializedLambda` (although exactly the same code) returns a different `implMethodKind` depending on the project.

Comment: Well, who produces the `SerializedLambda`?

Comment: I do, using the following class: https://github.com/jobrunr/jobrunr/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/jobrunr/jobs/details/SerializedLambdaConverter.java. So, the serialization happens exactly in the same way yet for some reason the `implMethodKind` is different.

Comment: *That’s* the code you should include in your question, instead of letting us search for the differences in the revisions of the calling code.

Comment: But to answer your question, as asked, [`SerializedLambda`’s constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/SerializedLambda.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.Class,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,int,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Object%5B%5D)) is `public`, so nothing stops you from constructing a new `SerializedLambda` with implMethodKind==5 when it is 7, before returning.

Comment: Sorry about not providing you with the `SerializedLambdaConverter`. The thing is: I don't want to construct it myself, currently it's the JVM (with some magic doing). I need it to find out which lambda is being scheduled as it contains all the details and parameters.
But I do not understand why in the same JVM, the current `SerializedLambdaConverter` is returning different results. Does this make more sense?

Comment: That’s why I said, “your question, as asked”, because you only asked “Is there a way so I can change the implMethodKind in JobRunr to also be 5?”. So your actual question is “Why do I get different values for implMethodKind?”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to check, could you try and modify your `.idea/compiler.xml`, this part:

```
   <bytecodeTargetLevel target="17">
      <module name="JobRunr.tests.e2e-elasticsearch-gson.test" target="11" />
      <module name="JobRunr.tests.e2e-elasticsearch-jackson.test" target="11" />
      <module name="JobRunr.tests.e2e-json-gson.test" target="11" />
      <module name="JobRunr.tests.e2e-mariadb-gson.test" target="11" />
      <module name="JobRunr.tests.e2e-mariadb-jackson.test" target="11" />
      <module name="JobRunr.tests.e2e-mongo-gson.test" target="11" />
      <module name="JobRunr.tests.e2e-mongo-jackson.test" target="11" />
      <module name="JobRunr.tests.e2e-mysql-gson.test" target="11" />
      <module name="JobRunr.tests.e2e-mysql-jackson.test" target="11" />
      <module name="JobRunr.tests.e2e-oracle-gson.test" target="11" />
      <module name="JobRunr.tests.e2e-oracle-jackson.test" target="11" />
      <module name="JobRunr.tests.e2e-postgres-gson.test" target="11" />
      <module name="JobRunr.tests.e2e-postgres-jackson.test" target="11" />
      <module name="JobRunr.tests.e2e-redis-gson.test" target="11" />
      <module name="JobRunr.tests.e2e-redis-jackson.test" target="11" />
      <module name="JobRunr.tests.e2e-sqlserver-gson.test" target="11" />
      <module name="JobRunr.tests.e2e-sqlserver-jackson.test" target="11" />
      <module name="JobRunr.tests.e2e-ui.main" target="11" />
      <module name="JobRunr.tests.e2e-ui.test" target="11" />
      <module name="JobRunr.tests.e2e-vm-jdk.test" target="11" /> <----- here
    </bytecodeTargetLevel>
```

Comment: Hi @nataliia-dziubenko, won't help - I even compiled without intellij in a Java 17 docker container.

Comment: Hi Ronald, sorry if that's not helping, I managed to reproduce your problem only when compiled with wrong target version (even without JobRunr code involved). I see you have both gradle and maven configs, which one are you using? If maven, could you try one more thing in your pom, set the jdk 17 profile to be `<activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>`

Comment: Well, Maven is used and I tested with JDK 17 profile using `<activeByDefault>true<activeByDefault>`. To be 100% sure, I checked the class header in this test https://github.com/jobrunr/jobrunr/blob/1c181f95e160821d809681d7f93ad6b6f1963f64/tests/e2e-vm-jdk/src/test/java/org/jobrunr/tests/e2e/E2EJDKTest.java which showed 61 matching Java SE 17.

Comment: Could you attach the javap output of the `GeoService` class?

Comment: Done! See the original SO question. And, thanks for the help!

Comment: One minute later I noticed that's the wrong class... it should be GeoService and that has been compiled with major version: 52!  

Answer (score 1):

The `SerializedLambda` reflects how the lambda expression has been compiled which is, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61454800/2711488), compiler dependent. Therefore, the result does not dependent on the Java runtime version but the compiler used for the class containing the lambda expression and there is no runtime option to alter the outcome.

Besides the choice of compiling the body into an instance method or into a `static` method receiving `this` as a parameter, the compiler is free to encode the invocation of the private instance method as an `invokespecial` or `invokevirtual` behavior. Both is equally valid.

We can use the following program to self-inspect the encoded invocation:

```java
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.spi.ToolProvider;

public class LambdaBinary {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ToolProvider.findFirst("javap").ifPresent(new LambdaBinary()::print);
    }
  
    private void print(ToolProvider tp) {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
        tp.run(pw, pw, "-v", LambdaBinary.class.getName());
        StringBuffer b = sw.getBuffer();
        System.out.append(b,
            b.lastIndexOf("BootstrapMethods:"),
            b.lastIndexOf("InnerClasses:"));
    }
}
```

When compiled with `javac` version 8 to 14 or using Eclipse’s compiler, the result will be something like

```
BootstrapMethods:
  0: #85 REF_invokeStatic java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.metafactory:(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite;
    Method arguments:
      #92 (Ljava/lang/Object;)V
      #94 REF_invokeSpecial LambdaBinary.print:(Ljava/util/spi/ToolProvider;)V
      #97 (Ljava/util/spi/ToolProvider;)V
```

when compiled with `javac` of JDK 15 or newer, it prints something like

```
BootstrapMethods:
  0: #85 REF_invokeStatic java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.metafactory:(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite;
    Method arguments:
      #92 (Ljava/lang/Object;)V
      #94 REF_invokeVirtual LambdaBinary.print:(Ljava/util/spi/ToolProvider;)V
      #97 (Ljava/util/spi/ToolProvider;)V
```

As said, this difference between `REF_invokeSpecial` and `REF_invokeVirtual` is reflected by the `SerializedLambda` and the only thing you can do, is to adapt your code to handle both values the same way.